# CSS Animation not reversing on hover-out

Tags: html, css, transition

When I hover this button the slide down transition is working, but when I remove the hover, the element just disappears, without the animation reverting.

The `transition` property is on the element itself, and not on the `:hover` pseudo element, so I don't really see what the issue could be here.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/pilfton/pen/wvPrQjX

#### HTML

```html
<div class="availability-container">
  <button class="availability-button">
    Button
  </button>

  <ul class="availability-content">
    <li>testing</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

#### SCSS

```css
.availability-container {
    overflow: hidden;

    .availability-button {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        background-color: #ffe1e1;
        padding: 5px 10px;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }

    ul.availability-content {
        padding: 0;
        list-style-type: none;
        visibility: hidden;
        transform: translateY(-20px);
        transition: transform .2s ease-in-out;
        opacity: 0;
    }

    &:hover .availability-content {
        visibility: visible;
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateY(0%);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is very simple. So, no worries :)

You implement transition only for transform.

`transition: transform .2s ease-in-out;`

Change this like this.

`transition: all .2s ease-in-out;` or `transition: transform .2s ease-in-out, opacity .2s ease-in-out;`.

So you can see both transform and opacity animating.

You can test it here => https://codepen.io/cooskun/pen/yLPzQwm

Happy coding!

Comment: That's a silly mistake of me! Thank you for your answer

Comment: You're welcome! Mistakes happen. No worries :)